# Drawing Libgdx Bitmap Font on Android THREAD ERROR

Tags: java, android, multithreading, libgdx

I have really simple code in Libgdx project, and it doesn't work on Android, but pretty works on Desktop. On Android I have this errors after a couple of render times:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer(1314): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
E/OpenGLRenderer(1314): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
W/GL2JNIView(1314): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
 E/EGL_genymotion(1314): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
E/EGL_genymotion(1314): tid 1328: eglGetConfigAttrib(573): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
A/libc(1314): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x971ae008 (code=2), thread 1328 (Thread-96)
```

Show Method:

```
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("cutive.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 30;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
```

Resize Method:

```
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.update();
```

Render Method:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "helloabssdadaa", 100, -300);
    batch.end();
```

Comment: Include more information about the crash, just that one line is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded solution. It was on the splash screen. Dont dispose anything in splash.